# How can I script inverting screen colors?

Tags: terminal, macos, accessibility

And, more generally, how can I change accessibility settings via the command line?

Worth pointing out that I'm pretty comfortable with bash already- coming from a systems administration / *nix background- but I just don't know which files to edit or tools to use.

To clarify, I am not asking [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/178313/change-accessibility-setting-on-mac-using-terminal), the resolution of which modifies a setting under Security and Privacy. What I want to do is change a setting directly under Accessibility. I'll grant the title of that question is misleadingly similar, but the content is entirely divorced from my intent.

Answer (score 4):

- If it's okay to give `Terminal.app` permanent access to `Accessibility`:

  1. Open `System Preferences`
  2. Go to `Security & Privacy` section
  3. In `Privacy` tab, click on the lock in bottom left and enter your password to enable editing
  4. Select `Accessibility` from left side list and then check `Terminal` checkbox in right side list (if there is no `Terminal` checkbox here you might run step 5 once and then back to this step)
  5. Open `Terminal` and run this line (it uses AppleScript):

     ```
      osascript -e "tell application \"System Preferences\"" -e "activate" -e "reveal anchor \"Seeing_Display\" of pane id \"com.apple.preference.universalaccess\"" -e "tell application \"System Events\" to tell process \"System Preferences\"" -e "click the checkbox \"Invert colors\" of window \"Accessibility\"" -e "end tell" -e "quit" -e "end tell"
     ```

     repeating previous steps for the future is not needed.
- If it's not okay to give direct access:

  1. Open `System Preferences`
  2. Go to `Keyboard` section
  3. In `Shortcuts` tab, Select `Accessibility` from left side list and then check `Invert colors` in right side list (Default shortcut is `ctrl`+`alt`+`cmd`+`8`).
  4. Open `Terminal` and run this line (it uses AppleScript):

     ```
      osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\"" -e "key code 28 using {control down, option down, command down}" -e "end tell"
     ```

     repeating previous steps for the future is not needed.

You can write those codes in external script files and run with `osascript invertColors.scpt`

Answer (score 3):

**to invert:** `printf '\e[?5h'`

---

**to un-invert:** `printf '\e[?5l'`

Comment: I know how to use terminal escape sequences. That's not the question I'm asking. Please try to understand what's being asked before you answer. :P

Comment: ah you mean the entire screen. I have never used mac, but this is still useful if you want your terminal to flash after updating (what do you mac'ers use? homebrew?). Sorry about that and good luck with the osascripting. Also, after reading your question a second time, it still looks a bit like you meant the terminal if reading quickly.

Answer (score 0):

```
defaults find invert
```

leads to

```
defaults read com.apple.CoreGraphics DisplayUseInvertedPolarity
```

Which returns 0 = normal, 1 = inverted.
Alas, writing did not affect the screen in Mojave 10.14.6 but did confuse the ⌃⌥⌘8 shortcut.

Comment: More info but no solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511304/how-to-programmatically-invert-screen-colors-on-mac

Answer (score 0):

On macOS Monterey or newer it’s now possible to toggle Smart and Classic Invert using the new Shortcuts app. Search for "Invert" in the Action list when creating a new shortcut.

[Run shortcuts from the command line](https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts-mac/run-shortcuts-from-the-command-line-apd455c82f02/mac)